# passing array as parameters, stored procedures don't update result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have an int[] and pass it as parameter to a procedure, when the method is called, no error is reported but nothing is updated in the database. There may be something wrong in my Add() since the Stored Procedure is written by another programmer. I cannot modify this stored procedure so everything must be solved in the Add().

FYI, the Add() takes an array of userIDs and a groupID as parameters, format them and run the stored procedure. The stored procedure inserts userIDs and groupID into the DB

```
For example:
if userIDs=[1,2,3] and groupID=4, 
then I want the following data to be inserted into the DB
userID    groupID
1            4
2            4
3            4
```

The stored procedure

```
USE [xyz]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSaveSomething] 

            @groupID INT, 
            @userIDs TEXT
        AS
        BEGIN

            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            DECLARE @handle INT
            EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @userIDs

            DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE i_GroupID = @groupID AND i_NetworkUserID IN (SELECT [ID] FROM OPENXML (@handle, 'ROOT/VAL', 1) WITH ([ID] INT))

            INSERT INTO tbl1 (i_NetworkUserID, i_GroupID)
            SELECT [ID], @groupID FROM OPENXML (@handle, 'ROOT/VAL', 1) WITH ([ID] INT)

            EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
        END
```

The Add()

```
public void AddUsers(int[] UserIDs, int GroupID)
        {
                List<int> testList = new List<int>();

                foreach (int id in UserIDs)
                {
                    testList.Add(id);
                }

                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                xs.Serialize(ms, testList);

                string resultXML = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@userIDs", resultXML);
                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@groupID", GroupID);
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spSaveSomething @groupID, @userIDs",
                    param2, param1);

        }
```

Comment: hello, is there anyone here

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `int[]` into a string with Comma seprated and then in Stored Prodedure, us `in` ie

```
WHERE i_NetworkUserID in @UserIds
```

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing if this works. I tired myself but I didn't manage to do it correctly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

for me, your approach a little bit complicated.

I suggest to rewrite your procedure like

```
alter procedure [dbo].[spSaveSomething] 
(
    @groupID int, 
    @userIDs nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @tmp_Users table (ID int primary key)

    insert into @tmp_Users
    select T.C.value('.', 'int')
    from @userIDs.nodes('List/ID') as T(C)

    delete from tbl1
    where
        i_GroupID = @group_ID and
        i_NetworkUserID in (select ID from @tmp_Users)

    insert into tbl1 (i_NetworkUserID, i_GroupID)
    select ID, @groupID
    from @tmp_Users

    -- actually it's strange - you deleting users and then inserting
    -- may be you wanted to do this:

    -- delete from tbl1
    -- where
    --    i_GroupID = @group_ID and
    --    i_NetworkUserID not in (select ID from @tmp_Users)

    -- insert into tbl1 (i_NetworkUserID, i_GroupID)
    -- select U.ID, @groupID
    -- from @tmp_Users as U
    -- where
    --     not exists (
    --         select T.*
    --         from tbl1 as T
    --         where T.i_GroupID = @group_ID and T.i_NetworkUserID = U.ID
    --     )
end
```

and your xml generation like

```
var userIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var userXML = new XElement("List", a.Select(x => new XElement("ID", x))).ToString();
// so userXML = "<List><ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID><ID>3</ID></List>"
```

hope that helps